# Is there a function like substringFromIndex that uses less memory?

Tags: iphone, string, memory, substring

Is there a function in the IOS Api that is like substringFromIndex excepts uses a lot less memory (I am using VERY VERY large strings). If I would have to make that function how would I go about doing that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a way to make a function like that , and how would i go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it's kind of roundabout and potentially dangerous

Here's what you do:

```
NSString *veryLargeString = ...;
NSUInteger startingIndex = ...;
NSData *veryLargeStringData = [veryLargeString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

const void *bytes = [veryLargeStringData bytes];
const void *subBytes = bytes + startingIndex;
NSUInteger subLength = [veryLargeStringData length] - startingIndex;

NSString *substring = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:subBytes length:subLength encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding freeWhenDone:NO];
```

What is this doing:

1. It's getting the very large string as a series of bytes; I'm *pretty* sure this doesn't actually copy the bytes, but be sure to use Instruments to verify.  If you can get this super long string as an `NSData` to begin with instead of an `NSString`, then you can be much more confident that nothing's going to get copied.
2. Get the actual byte buffer from the `NSData`
3. Index into the byte buffer by using some pointer arithmetic
4. Figure out how much of the buffer is left
5. Create a new `NSString` with the byte buffer, but telling it to *NOT* copy the bytes, and to *NOT* free the buffer when the `NSString` is deallocated

So, why is this dangerous?  Basically, if the byte buffer disappears from underneath the `NSStrings`, Bad Things™ can happen (likely crashing).

However, if you're smart about it, this will allow you to create substrings without copying the underlying bytes.

---

**Devious thought**:

You could make `veryLargeString` a retained associated object on `substring` (i.e., basically make `substring` an owner of `veryLargeString`).  This would ensure that `veryLargeString` lives at least as long as `substring` does.  You'd do that like this:

```
static char ParentStringKey;

objc_setAssociatedObject(substring, &ParentStringKey, veryLargeString, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
```

When `substring` is deallocated, it'll also automatically release its retain on `veryLargeString`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try it right now. Outstanding explanation also

Comment: You may also use the `cStringUsingEncoding:` method of `NSString`, to get a `char *`, and then use the C library functions from `<string.h>`, or simply pointer arythmetics, to process it. May save a few bytes of memory, as it doesn't use a temporary `NSData` object. You'll still be able to use the `initWithBytesNoCopy:` method for the final `NSString` object.

Comment: +1 for Bad Things(TM) ... well, and for a really nifty solution.

Comment: @Macmade sure you could do that to go directly to the byte buffer. however the size of an `NSData` is only going to be a few extra bytes; probably not worth worrying about.  Plus, I think it'd be easier to manage the lifetime of an `NSData` versus a `char*` (for the same reasons why retain/release is preferable over malloc/free).

Comment: Updated answer, now with 42% more Deviousness!